# RestKit installation warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I've started learning RestKit and installed it with cocoapods just like the [GitHub](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) installation says, the problem come after i've completed the process i got 12 warnings from the framework

[image]

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: What version have you specified in your pod file?

Comment: i'm using version 0.20.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an old version. Go to github, find the latest version number and upgrade to that. At the time of writing that is version 0.22.0, which is still months old so will still have some build warnings, but you don't really need to worry about them (Xcode is being more specific about reporting is all, that doesn't mean things shouldn't be fixed, and they are being fixed, but most aren't an issue for you).

If you really don't like the warnings, switching to the HEAD of the development branch will reduce most issues as it has the most up-to-date code.

Comment: To upgrade to the latest version i just need to re install the Podfile with the recent version?

Comment: Yes, change the version and then pod install

Comment: Thanks Wain! it didn't fixed all warnings but it took some of them off.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking :head as of 4/19 solved this issue.

```
platform :ios, '7.1'
pod 'RestKit', :head
```